# How to create mock for AWS resources like dynamoDB for local development in nodejs lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mocking, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know how can I mock AWS resources and their operations for local development? Currently I have a lambda that inserts values into dynamoDB. I'm not looking for test case purpose (will need these later on), but if possible I can do these operations without calling actual services?

Currently I have created a mockdb.js file with similar values of dynamoDB but to run the code everytime on my machine, I have to comment out the actual aws code and mention-

```
import {data} from '../mockdb.js';
const list = insertTable(data) // everytime I have to add this instead of aws dynamoDB sdk
```

Is their a easier way? Eg. For react applications we have mockservers to mimic route responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to test and develop all AWS services locally but there are some solutions which cover some services and use cases (the list is not exhaustive):

**Localstack**: https://github.com/localstack/localstack

**SAM framework** allows local testing and developing for some services (Lambdas and API Gateway): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-test-and-debug.html

There is a downloadable local version for **DynamoDB**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

For missing services you have to develop your own mock services/functions and use them for developing testing.